# Multitasking issue

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have am creating a game.Then game has a timer 100 sec ,which move to zero like 99,98,97...

Now when we lose the game we retry ...but this time the timer decrements of2...lieke 98,96,94

if we lose again and retry this time the difference is of 3...

i noticed that when we lose and retry the timer function is called twice so it make decrement of 2...similarly if we retry for the 3rd time the timer is called three times and so on?

what is this issue?please urgent help required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your timer is being started each time you retry. The first time, you have one timer running. Then the second time, you have two timers, and the third time three... You may need to stop the previous timer before retrying so that you only have one timer running.

Comment: I'm sorry, you'll have to work that out on your own. I don't know anything about iPhone programming.